# SXC 9 update 2 Installation error while "Generating Catalog Templates"

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework

I am getting the below error on Installation of Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 update 2.

> Generating Catalog Templates Install-SitecoreConfiguration:Value
>   cannot be null.Parameter name: key

[image]

The Server logs inside

> 6 11:00:48 ERROR CtxMsg.Error.EntityNotFound:
>   Text=Core.block.LoadEnvironment.EnvironmentCouldNotBeFound:
>   Environment=HabitatAuthoring 6 11:00:48 ERROR
>   PipelineAbort:Core.block.LoadEnvironment.EnvironmentCouldNotBeFound:
>   Environment=HabitatAuthoring 10 11:00:51 ERROR
>   ClientCertificateValidationMiddleware: Certificate with thumbprint
>   DBD3361F1F6197DC7F835B440E8F2FE38586DBA5 does not have a matching
>   Thumbprint.

The logs says as below"

```
> Generating Catalog Templates ...
> ********************** Command start time: 20180725111929
> ********************** PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-RestMethod): "    
>         Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key       
>         
>          body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
>          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top:
> -5px}
>          b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
>          H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
>          H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
>          pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
>          .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
>          .version {color: gray;}
>          .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
>          .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
>          @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
>           pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
>          }
>          @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
>           pre { width: 280px; }
>          }
>             Server Error in '/' Application.
> 
>              Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key 
> 
>              Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
> for more information about the error and where it originated in the
> code.
> 
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
> null.Parameter name: key
> 
> Source Error:  The source code that generated this unhandled exception
> can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please
> follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:1. Add a
> &quot;Debug=true&quot; directive at the top of the file that generated
> the error. Example: &nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;%@ Page Language=&quot;C#&quot;
> Debug=&quot;true&quot; %&gt;or:2) Add the following section to the
> configuration file of your application:&lt;configuration&gt;
> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;system.web&gt;
> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;compilation
> debug=&quot;true&quot;/&gt;
> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/system.web&gt;&lt;/configuration&gt; Note that
> this second technique will cause all files within a given application
> to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that
> particular file to be compiled in debug mode.Important: Running
> applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead.
> You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before
> deploying into production scenario.
> 
> Stack Trace:   [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter
> name: key]   
> System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey
> key) +14761472   
> Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogRepository.GetEntityView(String
> sitecoreId, String viewName, String forAction, String itemId) +133   
> Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.Templates.CatalogTemplateGenerator.BuildCatalogTemplates(Database
> database) +636   
> ASP.siteutilitypages_generatecatalogtemplates_aspx.Page_Load(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) +246    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
> +103    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +3811
> 
>             Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0"
> >> TerminatingError(Invoke-RestMethod): "
>         Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key
>         
>          body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
>          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top:
> -5px}
>          b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
>          H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
>          H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
>          pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
>          .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
>          .version {color: gray;}
>          .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
>          .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
>          @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
>           pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
>          }
>          @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
>           pre { width: 280px; }
>          }
> 
>             Server Error in '/' Application.
> 
>              Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key 
> 
>              Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
> for more information about the error and where it originated in the
> code.
>     Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key
> 
>             Source Error:   
> 
> The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be
> shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one
> of the below steps, then request the URL:1. Add a
> &quot;Debug=true&quot; directive at the top of the file that generated
> the error. Example: &nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;%@ Page Language=&quot;C#&quot;
> Debug=&quot;true&quot; %&gt;or:2) Add the following section to the
> configuration file of your application:&lt;configuration&gt;
> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;system.web&gt;
> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;compilation
> debug=&quot;true&quot;/&gt;
> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/system.web&gt;&lt;/configuration&gt; Note that
> this second technique will cause all files within a given application
> to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that
> particular file to be compiled in debug mode.Important: Running
> applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead.
> You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before
> deploying into production scenario.
> 
> Stack Trace:  [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter
> name: key]
> System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey
> key) +14761472   
> Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogRepository.GetEntityView(String
> sitecoreId, String viewName, String forAction, String itemId) +133   
> Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.Templates.CatalogTemplateGenerator.BuildCatalogTemplates(Database
> database) +636   
> ASP.siteutilitypages_generatecatalogtemplates_aspx.Page_Load(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) +246    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
> +103    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +3811
> 
> Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
> ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0
```

Comment: Seems that the previous step was not finished as expected and you have some trouble. I think that bootstraping failed in some previous step

Comment: Yes,I got the error with install Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.2.2.86.update Package https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/sxc-9-update-2-installation-error-sitecore-commerce-engine-connect-2-2-86-updat. So I did the installation of this as a package and proceeded to the next steps by removing this step from Master_SingleServer.json

Comment: Did you able to fix this issue? Can you please help me know what steps you followed to overcome th

Comment: I am facing this issue. Please share how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue and fixed it. Please refer to my answer here
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/23435/4763